# Handling URLs in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, url-rewriting, yaml

I want a particular handler "/OldVideos" to be invoked when URLs which end with ".aspx" are requested for.

How do I fit this in the app.yaml file?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL and file path patterns use Regular Expression syntax. So, you can write a regular expression for paths ending with `.aspx` such as

```
- url: /.*\.aspx  
    script: oldvideos.py
```

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#About_app_yaml